# performing a formati for a date yyyymm by hand isn't working Quicksight

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Im trying to perform a transformation of a coludate in QS

here is the code for calculated field

```
    concat(
        toString(
            extract(
                'YYYY', 
                {created_at}
            )
        ),
        toString(
            ifelse(
                extract(
                    'MM', 
                    {created_at}
                )<10,
                concat(
                    '0',
                    toString(
                        extract(
                            'MM', 
                            {created_at}
                        )
                    )
                ),
                extract(
                    'MM', 
                    {created_at}
                )
            )                     
        )
    )
)
```

it works if I dont use the conditional, but I need it to add a 0 when is one of the first nine months of the year.

When I try to run it, it states that the sintaxis it's wrong and I should pick the option create, but I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: I don't use AmazonQS, but according to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/formatDate-function.html) you can do simply: `formatDate({myDateField}, "yyyyMM")` ?

Comment: When I use that it states that the function has a unadmitted format

Answer (score 0):

Are you really planning to use such a complex expression?

Why not:

```
CAST (
    DATE_PART(year,created_at) * 100 + DATE_PART(month, created_at)
 AS CHAR(6)
)
```

?

Comment: I cant edit the query, I've tried with the datased for a calculated field and didn't worked

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: wrong sintax, use create option

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this
 `left(toString({created_at}), 7)`

Which left the date like yyyy-mm but works.